# Meaning of a sentence from a self help book of Orison Swett Marden

Tags: meaning

I'm not a native English speaker and cannot get the full meaning of this part of Orison Swett Marden's self help book *"Pushing to the front"*:

> "How hard I worked at that tremendous shorthand, and all improvement
> appertaining to it," said Dickens. "I will only add to what I have
> already written of my perseverance at this time of my life, and of a
> patient and continuous energy which then began to be matured."

It is in the chapter 23 which is entitled *"The reward of persistence"*.

Comment: If you read the [full paragraph](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Charles_Dickens_s_works_Charles_Dickens/PB8GAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22How%20hard%20I%20worked%20at%20that%20tremendous%20shorthand,%20and%20all%20improvement%20appertaining%20to%20it,%22%20said%20Dickens.%20%22I%20will%20only%20add%20to%20what%20I%20have%20already%20written%20of%20my%20perseverance%20at%20this%20time%20of%20my%20life,%20and%20of%20a%20patient%20and%20continuous%20energy%20which%20then%20began%20to%20be%20matured.%22&pg=PA368&printsec=frontcover) from the works of Charles Dickens, I believe the meaning will

Comment: What particular part of the paragraph is unclear? Is there a particular phrase that isn't understood? If you understand the individual words, what is making the whole unclear? If you break the paragraph into two, can you understand the first or second half?

Comment: I think have the whole picture, but I am not sure. I want to translate this part, so I have to know the exact meaning. Does it mean "I am going to add perserverence and patient and energy to what I have written (these shorthands) to make it matured"?

Comment: I interpret it this way—but it's only my subjective interpretation, and could be wrong: *I worked very hard to summarize my perseverance, and my maturing patient and continuous energy. I can only add in volume to what I've already written, not change it substantially.*

Comment: If you look at the original, it says that he has ***already*** **written of** those things. So, he's not *adding* those things to it after the fact.